# cURL: upload multipart-form json + images

Tags: curl

How can I construct a multipart-form upload with curl such as

- upload a json (named "command")
- upload images (named "certificates")

simultaneously in one go?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution myself:

```
curl -v localhost:8080
    -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'
    --form 'command={"test": "hello"};type=application/json'
    --form 'certificates=@example.jpg;type=image/jpeg'
```

This example assumes that the server on port 8080 expects that JSON structure and the image is in the current directory when you execute curl.

Multiple images can uploaded just by appending another --form